# Solving $(5A^T)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-3 & -1\\5 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ for $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this equation and I'm trying to solve for $A$
$$(5A^T)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-3 & -1\\5 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

I did something like:
$$\begin{bmatrix}5a_1 & 5a_2\\5a_3 & 5a_4\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-3 & -1\\5 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$det =25a_1a_4-25a_3a_2$$

$$5a_1=(25a_1a_4-25a_3a_2)\times-3$$
$$5a_2=(25a_1a_4-25a_3a_2)\times-1$$
$$\dots=(25a_1a_4-25a_3a_2)\times\dots$$

I'm I on the right path? Because it's leading nowhere and I feel like I'm missing some simpler point

Comment: I would first calculate the inverse of $\left( \begin{matrix} -3 & -1 \\ 5 & 2 \end{matrix}\right)$.

Comment: **HINT:** $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way is to use the following:

- If $A^{-1} = B$, then $A = B^{-1}$.
- If $A^T = B$, then $A = B^T$.

These facts allow you to shift the operations of inverse and transpose to the known matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Given:
$$
(5A^T)^{-1}=B
$$
Then:
$$
(5A^T)=B^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1\\ 
5 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore:
$$
A=(1/5)(B^{-1})^T=(1/5)
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 5\\ 
-1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\begin{bmatrix}-3&-1\\ 5&2\end{bmatrix}$. The equation $\,\,5\bigl(^{\mathrm  t\!}A\bigl)^{-1}=B$  is equivalent to $\,\,A=\dfrac15\bigl(^{\mathrm t\mkern-1.5mu}B\bigl)^{-1}$.

Calculate the inverse of $\,^{\mathrm  t\mkern-1.5mu}B=\begin{bmatrix}-3&5\\ -1&2\end{bmatrix}$ using Gauß's pivot: $\,\bigl(^{\mathrm t\mkern-1.5mu}B\bigl)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-2&5\\ -1&3\end{bmatrix}$, so:
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}-\dfrac25&1\\ -\dfrac15&\dfrac35\end{bmatrix}. $$